# Linux C++ Application Setting Configured by XML file

Tags: c++, xml

I am working with a C++ project whose application setting is a simple text file. Now i want to replace the file with XML based configuration. So which xml parser should i use?

Comment: What have you checked? What are your skills with C++? Can you afford using boost? Wouldn't boost property_tree fill your bill?

Comment: it depends of size xml file. for a litle xml you can use `dom`. for large file try use `sax`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) or [TinyXML++](http://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/docs/ticpp.html), it's small and easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the boost::property_tree, as someone already mentioned.
[Here is a nice tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html) for using it to read/write xml.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of choice.  Selecting a parser with XPATH support is often very handy in this circumstance.  [libxml+](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/) with [libXml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) does the job nicely - and libxml2 is included in just about any Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/), it may be good replace for xml.